# How to stop main thread from another thread in c/c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I want to stop the main thread from another thread if captured `VK_ESCAPE` key and resume main thread when the user presses any key.
I intend to construct "ThreadProc1" thread to catch pressed key:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(LPVOID param){
    while(1){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)){
            //Stop the main thread
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main thread can't be stopped without exiting the program

Comment: Do you mean you want to *kill* the thread, or just *suspend* it?

Comment: Also, I think your design is a little backwards. Normally you spawn threads to perform other work, while the main thread continue to handle the main events (like checking for keyboard presses).

Comment: I want suspend it

Comment: Since you are using the Windows API, I suggest you take a look at [the list of process and thread functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm sure you could find something there.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  >Also, I think your design is a little backwards.< Suspending main thread in win  API may result in that OS would consider program  "hung": main thread is what is running the message pump. That design would result in OS marking application "not responding" after sometime, because message pump buffer will overflow. There is "legal" way to stop main message pump, it is to create modal window which got own pump, but if I recall right, it will work in main thread still.

Comment: You need to step back and try to gain a proper understanding of how threads and input works

Comment: suspend thread is very simply - call `SuspendThread` and then `ResumeThread`. handle you can get by `OpenThread`, `dwThreadId` of "main" thread pass in parameter when create you working thread. BUT I sure really no sense suspend your thread at arbitrary point (what if it at suspend moment in critical section ?) but fount more another  solution of your problem

Comment: @RbMm forgot to mention that handle from GetCurrentThread is meaningful only inside thread it created. One need to DuplicateHandle it.

Comment: @Swift - I mean thread id, but not constant -2, returned by `GetCurrentThread` - so 2 way. - or have thread id, open it when need from working thread, or just open handle to main thread and pass it to working. but in all case use `SuspendThread` bad idea

Comment: @RbMm Oh, I assumed so because SuspendThred uses handle, not unique  thread id (which can be get by GetCurrentThreadId), one would need OpenThread, which is restricted.. Um, do child thread always have permission to use OpenThread on ids for same process?

Comment: At the moment, I would suggest you to switch the roles of your threads. Move the code of `ThreadProc1` into main thread, while code from the main could go into `ThreadProc1`. That way, you would pause the `ThreadProc1` when `VK_ESCAPE` is pressed, leaving your main thread intact, which is more natural and correct. It would be really nice if you could explain briefly what your app is supposed to do. That way the community could offer you better assistance and more detailed advice.

Comment: @Swift - "do child thread always have permission to use OpenThread on ids for same process?" - in general yes, except some of threads use impersonation

Answer (score 1):

Do not do that. Either: 1) Make primary thread to skip all meaningful actions when it receives message from Esc key pressed until it is pressed again.  2) Use CreateEvent and have main thread WaitForMultipleObjects on it, then wake it up with SetEvent from other thread, or on timeout.

Primary thread if it started message pump,  is "heart and brain" of Windows application, stopping it is equivalent of clinical death. "blocking" actions,from which it is possible to return,  like reading  from file, sockets, etc. are legal, prowided that other thread would not cause by deadlock. Sleeping is legal because thread could be woken up. Putting message pump thread into sleep without substitute for message pump is action of dubious virtue, such application  maybe considered "hung". drivers that stopped is such way will be killed, services hung for indefinite time, desktop GUI would offer user to stop the app (or will stop that app in enterprise environment, if admins were paranoid), and would mark it in taskbar "not responding", etc.

Comment: Windows applications do not have the notion of a *"main thread"*. There is a *"primary thread"*, but that's just your average thread who's only distinct feature is, that it was the first one created in a process. Blocking the primary thread has no adverse effect (unless that thread owns a GUI). `WaitForSingleObject` **does** block, and while it is legal to call it from a GUI thread, it will result in a hung GUI. [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx) is a better option (even if tricky to use).

Comment: With probability > 0.999 the first thread created is the GUI thread

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Software development is not an exercise in statistics. Besides, 99.9% of all statistics are made up of thin air.

Comment: @iinspectable I stand corrected, had brainfart, yes, i meant multipleobjects wait. and if OP isnt one of those who write entire application in API, then his GUI is in primary thread. In my language primary and main is same word and I didn't use naked API when i already knew english. Most frameworks initialize message pump in primary thread.actually, that doesnt neccassary should be GUi, e.g. services have own message pump but they dont access GUI. It is all about responding or not. in case of drivers, windows automatically kills and restarts those which stopped to respond for certain time.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm pointing out that it is often perfectly pragmatic to assume that the primary thread is the UI thread. If it isn't then so be it. But it usually is. That's all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's neither pragmatic, nor even necessary to make any assumptions about whether a GUI thread is the primary thread of a process. A thread, any thread, that needs to dispatch messages cannot block. Whether that is the primary thread, a GUI thread, or a thread without a GUI is not at all interesting. Your recommendation to make assumptions based on made-up statistics, that don't even buy you anything in the way of simplifying things is ill-advised.

Comment: @Swift: Your updated answer is still mostly wrong. Exchanging `WaitForSingleObject` with `WaitForMultipleObjects` doesn't buy you anything. I pointed out `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, because it can wait on waitable objects as well as messages. That sets it apart from the other APIs. Your analogy of the primary thread being the *"heart and brain"* also isn't very fitting, as it suggests that there is only one. However, a process can have any number of threads, and any thread can run a message loop.

Comment: @IInspectable OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

formally suspend thread is very easy - [`SuspendThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx) and then [`ResumeThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086(v=vs.85).aspx) - but :

> This function is primarily designed for use by debuggers. It is not
>   intended to be used for thread synchronization. Calling SuspendThread
>   on a thread that owns a synchronization object, such as a mutex or
>   critical section, can lead to a deadlock if the calling thread tries
>   to obtain a synchronization object owned by a suspended thread. To
>   avoid this situation, a thread within an application that is not a
>   debugger should signal the other thread to suspend itself. The target
>   thread must be designed to watch for this signal and respond
>   appropriately.

quite likely scenario - [`HeapAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`HeapFree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701(v=vs.85).aspx) called (and it called frequently on windows message processing) by thread at suspend time. and thread hold heap critical section. if working thread after this also direct or indirect(very high possibility of this) call to [`HeapAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx) (or any another heap function for same heap - usually this is main process heap) - you got deadlock.

you of course can say send some known message with event handle to main thread - main thread will be wait on event, until working thread not call `SetEvent` - but this is also bad and not quality solution.

UI thread must not do blocking wait at all, permanent wait on windows messages. i don not exactly know which task you try perform, but 100% sure that exist solution without blocking UI thread at all